# Why does boost zlib compressor throw weird error

Tags: c++, boost, zlib

I am trying to use boost zlib compressor. When i run following code, the program exits with -1 code even without printing "1":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include<zlib.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
    std::stringstream ss;
    boost::iostreams::filtering_ostreambuf fos;
    fos.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor(boost::iostreams::zlib::best_compression));
    fos.push(ss);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive archive(fos);
    std::string s = "HELLO!";
    archive << s;
    archive << 58;
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When i comment out line where i construct zlib_compressor, program works as expected, but without compressing anything. Why does this code not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the problem was. Program crashed because i didn't add zlib, lzma, bz2 and zstd libraries to run directory. All of these libraries are needed together and it doesn't matter which compression algorithm do you use.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works fine, though it won't do much. You're not modifying ss for the second print. :)
Your problem is more likely that as you're probably not linking boost statically and the required libraries are not available in the path => it crashes.

Here's what I have:

```
> g++ xx.cpp -lboost_iostreams -lboost_serialization
> ./a.out 
1

> echo $?
0
```

Comment: Do you mean that i should copy dynamic libraries to run directory? I copied boost iostreams, serialization and zlib. It still crashes :(.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was aiming at.

Comment: And also i don't know how to modify ss. How can i do this?

Comment: well you should modify it before adding it to the archive. push adds a copy. see: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/filtering_streambuf.html